# SQL Query show last value regarding the next one

Tags: mysql, sql

I will show you a problem I am facing.
I would like to have the last value of columns until the next value is smaller or zero
In the next image I hope to explain my problem more easily:

[image]

So, every time the value of "PartA" is greater than the next one, that value should be shown.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lead() function for this,

```
select id,parta,partb,time from 
 (
  select 
   id
   ,parta
   ,partb
   ,lead(parta) over (partition by id order by lineitem) nextval
  from sample_stk
)A
where parta>nextval
```

Comment: It looks like we don't have to consider the ID, so you can probably remove the partition clause. lineitem shall be the time column I suppose? And `LEAD` will give you null for the last line, so you must consider this in order to show that last line.

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner it's important to consider the ID in this case. It is the machine reference in our project. And yes, in this solution it doesn't show the last line for any ID... What should I do?

Comment: @joao25: The query shows rows where parta > nextval. nextval is null for each ID's last line, and you'd like it to be a very small value instead. You can use `where parta > coalesce(nextval,-1)` for this.

Comment: Or of course you could just use `where parta > nextval or nextval is null`.